# API gateway in kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress, api-gateway

I am still learning about microservices architecture and can't get a clear idea how to tackle a given problem.

Let's say I have a k8s cluster with some BE microservices, FE app or any other services deployed into it. I have also an ingress controller that does consumes traffic and route to services.

Somewhere inside that setup I would like to put API gateway, which would do some additional (customizable) stuff on the requests like authentication, logging, adding headers etc. We could wrap up this functionality as a reverse-proxy for the whole cluster. I have found three possible solutions:

AGW outside cluster in front of Ingress:

[image: Approach 1]

AGW as an Ingress Controller:

[image: Approach 2]

AGW inside cluster after Ingress:

[image: Approach 3]

In first approach AGW routes all traffic to ingress, but then we need to have a "private domain" that ingress will be exposed under. AGW will be exposed under public domain and route traffic to this private domain. That is not great, because Ingress is not exposed under the public domain. E.g. we faced a problem, when Ingress was doing some redirects and was using it's private domain in Location header instead of the public one.

In second approach AGW functionality is embedded in Ingress Controller, however I haven't find a suitable controller for our need. Building a custom Ingress Controller doesn't sound too good.

In third AGW is inside cluster, but then Ingress is not doing any routing. All routing (and load balancing) will happen in AGW.

Are there any other solutions? If not which of them would you recommend? Or maybe there is a different approach to included mentioned reverse-proxy funcionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second and third solution usually works best. The Ingress doesn't loadbalance, it's the service objects that configure the loadbalancing rules.

If you can manage to use an Api Gateway as Ingress Controller, like ambassador, or Istio (those are the ones I know about), that would be even better. You will remove an additional extra network hop.
Because ambassador and Istio are kubernetes minded, using kubernetes Resource objects, you can control whatever you like using those Ingress Controllers.

Comment: Thanks, all the time I was thinking that the Ingress is doing load balancing. But now it makes more sense, the third options seems to be more practical that I've expected.

Comment: https://thenewstack.io/ingress-controllers-or-the-kubernetes-gateway-api-which-is-right-for-you/ This blog says "Ingress controllers often include load balancing capabilities". But you said, "Ingress doesn't load balance". I am confused now @Leroy

Comment: You can use loadbalance capabilities without having an ingress specified. Depending on how the ingress controller is built (a.k.a. "often") the ingress either sends traffic to a service (which does loadbalancing) or the ingress controller can grab the services' endpoint definitions and configure each pod as a backend and do loadbalancing that way. The latter will skip an internal network hop in your k8s cluster and may improve performance. But not all ingress controllers work like this. If there is a feature on your service which the controller doesn't understand it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> In third AGW is inside cluster, but then Ingress is not doing any
> routing. All routing (and load balancing) will happen in AGW.

The AGW can be made such that it forward requests to another Service without doing anything special for routing and load balancing. It can forward mutated requests to the Service's ClusterIP or internal DNS which is in front of microservice Pods. You don't need Ingress just to load balance to a single Service.

Generally speaking, Ingress can be used for load balancing or not. When we want to load balance to more than one Service, we can use Ingress otherwise it's more useful for doing other things, e.g. TLS termination.